# « Démocrature » ou « Dictocratie » : pérennité etc. ?

Tags: néologismes, dictionnaires, connotation, fréquence-utilisation

Les mots-valises oxymores formés avec démocratie/dictature *démocrature* et *dictocratie* existent tous les [deux](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=DEMOCRATORSHIP) pour signifier une *démocratie* [*illibérale*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/illib%C3%A9ral) et [FranceTerme](https://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/AFET299) dispose du premier en ces termes « Régime politique qui, tout en respectant les règles formelles de la démocratie, notamment en matière d’élections, restreint les libertés publiques ou individuelles comme le fait une dictature ».

- L'ordre des éléments de ces mots crée-t-il une connotation différente entre les deux ?
- Lequel est-il le plus clair et pourquoi ?
- Les deux termes vont-ils s'imposer également ou l'un va-t-il supplanter l'autre et pourquoi, peut-on comparer à une autre paire similaire ?
- Le fait de retrouver le premier dans les débats de l'Assemblée nationale (France) et associé à *démocratie illibérale* dans FranceTerme (donc au Journal officiel de la République) a-t-il un impact sur la réponse ?

Answer (score 3):

On lit dans *démocrature* démocratie avec un suffixe qu'on peut soupçonner être péjoratif (rature) mais qui ne fait pas nécessairement penser à dictature. *Démocrature* est donc souvent accompagné lors de sa première utilisation d'une explication. J'aurais préféré *démoctature*, probablement plus identifiable.

*Dictocratie* est moins connu et plus difficile à interpréter, *dicto* ne faisant pas directement penser à dictature. *Dictocratie*: Le pouvoir des dictes ??

*Démocrature* semble s'être imposé. Je n'ai pas de paire similaire à proposer.